# Get directory of folder of the running jar

Tags: java, image, directory

Please help I want to get the root folder of running jar.

```
D:\My Folder\My Folder1\ myjarfile

D:\My Folder\My Folder1\My Folder2
```

I want to save image in MyFolder2 using myjarfile. I have difficulties in coding in getting path of the executable jar:

```
 String savePath = what goes there?(i want this "D:\My Folder\My Folder1\My Folder2")

 ImageIO.write(image1, "png",new File(savePath));
```

Answer (score 3):

***Do not save settings in the same directory as the Jar!***

It is better to save them in a (sub) directory of `user.home`.  That is a path that:

1. Is easy to reproduce.
2. The app. should have 'write permission'.

Also consider using [`Preferences`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) instead.

Comment: i need to save image in a folder for my image database. i dont know the code of making new folder as the default folder for image saving .

Comment: Was there a *question* hidden somewhere in that?